# Can't get e.preventDefault() to work

Tags: jquery, api, jsonp, preventdefault

I'd really appreciate if someone can look at my code and see why preventDefault isn't working.

The links seem to click into an error 404 page no matter what I try.

```
$(function() {

$.ajax({
    url: "http://linktoapi&callback=myMethod",
    timeout: 2000,
    jsonpCallback: "myMethod",
    jsonp: false,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data) {
        var newContent = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < data.listing.length; i++) { 
            newContent += '<p class="property-details">' + '<a href="' + data.listing[i].listing_id + '">' + data.listing[i].displayable_address + '</a></p>';

        }
        $('#content').html(newContent).hide().fadeIn(400);
    },
    error: function() { 
        $content.html('<div class="container">Please try again soon.</div>');
    }
});




$('.property-details a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
 $('#content').html("test").hide().fadeIn(400);
});

 });
```

Comment: Some of the HTML code that contains those anchors would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Proper event delegation requires the root element to exist at the time of binding. The click event can then be bound to all descendents of the root element whether they are added later or not. Check this documentation: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Try this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.property-details a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#content').html("test").hide().fadeIn(400);
});
```

Comment: I suspect the answer from @gregg-duncan is best and you could also create the objects in JQuery, with functions bound to them, and then append them.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your jquery code with code below as you are creating the anchor tags with ajax and for the code those does not exists so just load the `anchor click event` inside `success function of your ajax call` and it will work :

```
 $(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://linktoapi&callback=myMethod",
        timeout: 2000,
        jsonpCallback: "myMethod",
        jsonp: false,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(data) {
            var newContent = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < data.listing.length; i++) { 
                newContent += '<p class="property-details">' + '<a href="' + data.listing[i].listing_id + '">' + data.listing[i].displayable_address + '</a></p>';

            }
            $('#content').html(newContent).hide().fadeIn(400);
    $('.property-details a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
     $('#content').html("test").hide().fadeIn(400);
    });
        },
        error: function() { 
            $content.html('<div class="container">Please try again soon.</div>');
        }
    });

     });
```